# How to switch internet access over multiple ISP connected via LAN ports?

Tags: internet, lan

I have two lan ports, I am connected to two different ISP simultaneously.

I am aware that I can use only one ISP at a time. My problem is how to switch active ISP? I want to do this because sometimes one of the ISP becomes slow and I dont want to disconnect and reconnect because it will break my active connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this... if you change your default route, you will break all of your existing connections.

There is a section in the famous [Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/) about [routing for multiple upstream providers](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html).  But it's not light reading.  Expect to spend a good amount (possibly many hours, depending on your current level of network understanding) of time reading to understand all of the relevant concepts, then another good while with configuration and testing.